# Is it a mistake of the compiler or I misunderstand something?

Tags: arrays, swift

Please look at the code below and tell me why when I change the value in one element of array, the value in another elements are changing too? Thanks.

```
class C1 {
    var val = 0
}


class C2 {
    var arr = Array(count:3, repeatedValue: C1() )
}

let x = C2()

x.arr[0].val                              0
x.arr[1].val                              0
x.arr[2].val                              0

x.arr[0].val = 3

x.arr[0].val                              3
x.arr[1].val                              3 
x.arr[2].val                              3
```

[screenshot from x-code playground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN5h2.jpg)

Comment: Classes are *reference types.* You have created an array with 3 references to the *same instance* of the class object, compare e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921425/swift-creating-an-array-with-a-default-value-of-distinct-object-instances.

Comment: ... the key point being that a single instance, `C1()`, is initialized, whereafter a reference to this instance is used a repeated value in the array initializer. Hence, the above is not the same as `var arr = [C1(), C1(), C1()]`.