# How to modify a single element in an array with a custom type

Tags: swift

I'm trying to learn swift. When I do:

```
var myIntArray = [Int](count: 3, repeatedValue: 0)
myIntArray[0] = 1
myIntArray[1] = 11
myIntArray[2] = 111

// prints "my array: [1, 11, 111]"
NSLog("my int array: [%d, %d, %d]", myIntArray[0], myIntArray[1], myIntArray[2])
```

It works as expected, but when I wrap the int in a class like this:

```
class Foo {
    var bar = 0
}

var myWrappedIntArray = [Foo](count: 3, repeatedValue: Foo())
myWrappedIntArray[0].bar = 1
myWrappedIntArray[1].bar = 11
myWrappedIntArray[2].bar = 111

// prints "my array: [111, 111, 111]"
NSLog("my wrapped int array: [%d, %d, %d]", myWrappedIntArray[0].bar, myWrappedIntArray[1].bar, myWrappedIntArray[2].bar)
```

It seems to modify the entire array when trying to modify a single element. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Perhaps my argument for `repeatedValue` creates a single `Foo` instance and fills the array with pointers to this instance? But how to fix that?

Comment: Why aren't you using 'print' instead of "NSlog" ?

Comment: @RashmiRanjanmallick Because I'm used to using NSLog in iOS development, is that really relevant to the issue at hand?

Comment: No not relevant. I was just curious about that.

Comment: @MartinR thanks, that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

For this case it is better to use `Struct`:

```
struct Foo {
    var bar = 0
}

var myWrappedIntArray = [Foo](count: 3, repeatedValue: Foo())
myWrappedIntArray[0].bar = 1
myWrappedIntArray[1].bar = 11
myWrappedIntArray[2].bar = 111

// prints "my array: [1, 11, 111]"
print("my wrapped int array: [%d, %d, %d]", myWrappedIntArray[0].bar, myWrappedIntArray[1].bar, myWrappedIntArray[2].bar)
```

In you're case you are working with reference type value such as `[Foo]`. But `Struct` is value typed and create each element of the array unique.

You are referencing to the same object in `myWrappedIntArray[0].bar` and `myWrappedIntArray[n].bar`.

Because of the constructor.

```
var myWrappedIntArray = [Foo](count: 3, repeatedValue: Foo())
```

You repeat `Foo()` **reference** for  each element of the array instead of the creation of the new class for each index of the array.

Comment: My use case is different, but this is the smallest example I could write that reproduces my issue

Comment: i edit my answer.

Comment: How can I create the array with a `Foo` instance for every element? Do I need to create the array empty and append the `Foo` instances manually or is there an equivalent of `init(count: repeatedValue:)` that creates a new instance for every element?

Comment: One of the ways you describe. Take a look at answer of the MartinR. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921425/swift-creating-an-array-with-a-default-value-of-distinct-object-instances For you if it is possible use Structs instead of classes.