# How do you make multiple strings in a list fro swift?

Tags: swift

I was mainly wondering after doing some research, how do you make a multiple amount of strings in a list. For example...

```
    list = ["Dictionary" * 14]
```

Basically meaning that I would have 14 dictionaries. Yes I know that that code doesn’t work but I was wondering what might make that list have 14 dictionaries instead of an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use repeating functionality of the Arrays.

List of strings.

```
var list = Array(repeating: "Dictionary", count: 14)
```

Or if you would like to create 14 Dictionaries as data strcture.

```
var list = Array(repeating: [:], count: 14)
```

Comment: "I was mainly wondering after doing some research, how do you make a multiple amount of strings in a list."

Comment: @LeoDabus I am wondering if Dictionary is a data structure or just word in case of question

Comment: It's worth mentioning explicitly (since this can become a subtle bug) that the approach above is only appropriate for _value_ types, such as e.g. the `String` or `AnyHashable` examples above. When applying the `Array` repeating initializer upon reference types (`class`), a single object will be instantiated, whereafter _the reference to this object_ will be repeated in the array. E.g., for `class Foo { var bar: Int = 0; /* ... */ }`, with `var list = Array(repeating: Foo(), count: 14)`, the operation `list[3].bar = 42` will change the single instance pointed to by all members in `list`.

Comment: @dfri  ... as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921425/swift-creating-an-array-with-a-default-value-of-distinct-object-instances :)

Comment: @dfri Good point but there are cases where filling an array with multiple references to a single object of a reference type is useful. But it must be done knowing the possible pitfalls.