# Swift create object matrix

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and I am trying to create a array of arrays of a custom object. I did some research and what mostly came up online is:

```
Array(repeating: Array(repeating: [Object](), count: y), count: x)
```

or similar but I haven't been able to get them working for me. ( Deprecated because different swift versions,etc.. ) Right now I have

```
class ChessPiece {
// class definition...
}

class ChessBoard {
    var board: [[ChessPiece]] = []

    init() {
        board = [[ChessPiece(),ChessPiece(),ChessPiece()],
                 [ChessPiece(),ChessPiece(),ChessPiece()],
                 [ChessPiece(),ChessPiece(),ChessPiece()]]


    }
}
```

But what if I had 100 rows or columns? Isn't there a more efficient and direct way to create a matrix with x rows and y columns?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, and thus I believe this is a typo. `var matrix = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: [ChessPiece](), count: 10), count: 15)`, for instance, works perfectly for me.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Using `Arra(repeating)` will not give a matrix of distinct instances. Each row will have the same instance over and over.

Comment: @rmaddy that seems like what the OP is trying to do.

Comment: @rmaddy *"I haven't been able to get them working for me."* - I think that's what they want... Also, it should be `var matrix = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: ChessPiece(), count: 10), count: 15)`, without `[ChessPiece]()`, but `ChessPiece()`

Comment: @FrenchMajesty - do you want a matrix of unique instances of `ChessPiece` such that updating one instance has no effect on any other instance (like your attempt in your 2nd code snippet) or do you want each row to have n references to a single instance of `ChessPiece` where updating one piece affects every piece in the row (like your 1st code snipped)?

Comment: Related: [Swift: Creating an Array with a Default Value of distinct object instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921425/swift-creating-an-array-with-a-default-value-of-distinct-object-instances)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder The error I get when I do so is ".. cannot assign value of type <array>[array<object>] to type [[object]] "

Comment: @rmaddy yes I want unique instances for each ChessPiece

Comment: Then you can't use Array repeating with a class.

Comment: @rmaddy then how can one obtain something like my 2nd snippet without having to write them all out like I did. There's the option of maybe loops but I was hoping there would be a more direct way to do so

Comment: See the answer using a loop. Or see the link by Martin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just do with normal for-in loop

```
class ChessPiece {
// class definition...
}
class ChessBoard {
var board: [[ChessPiece]] = []

init(row: Int, column: Int) {
    for _ in 1...row {
        var innerArray: [ChessPiece] = []
        for _ in 1...column {
            innerArray.append(ChessPiece())
        }
        board.append(innerArray)
    }
  }
}
let chessBoard = ChessBoard(row: 8, column: 8)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you mentioned is fine `Array(repeating:count:)`.

This works on my playground:

```
struct ChessPiece {}

func makeChessPlate(dimension: Int) -> [[ChessPiece]] {
    return Array(repeating: Array(repeating: ChessPiece(), count: dimension), count: dimension)
}
print(makeChessPlate(dimension: 2)) // Result: [[ChessPiece, ChessPiece],[ChessPiece, ChessPiece]]
```

*EDIT*: Notice that my example works **only** because I used a **struct instead of a class**. On the contrary to classes, structs are copied by values, then this results in an array of unique objects.

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing as the code in the question because you don't a get a matrix of unique instances.

Comment: @rmaddy I am not sure of what you mean. Structs are copied by value then the result should be a matrix of unique instances, am I right ?

Comment: `ChessPiece` is a class, not a struct.

Comment: Yes but not in my example I gave. You're an experienced user, what do you advice me in this case? Commenting my solution to explain why this works only with structs or its better for me to remove the post ? Just trying to help !

Comment: I admit I didn't notice you used a struct. But since the OP is using a class, your use of struct may not be appropriate.

Answer (score -3):

You can use this loop to create a multidimensional array.

```
class ChessPiece{
}

var numColumns = 27
var numRows = 52
var array = [[ChessPiece]]()
for column in 0...numColumns {
    array.append(Array(repeating: ChessPiece(), count:numRows))
}
```

This would create an array of array of ChessPieces.

Comment: You should `map` over `0...numColumns` instead of doing repeated appends

Comment: This doesn't do the same thing as the code in the question because you don't a get a matrix of unique instances.

Comment: @rmaddy Are you sure about statement? I don't think question mentioned about any unique instance. We can always modify the code according to requirement.

Comment: We'll find out when the OP responds to my comment below the question.