# Swift For In Loop Iterating Through an Array of Custom Classes Doesn't Work

Tags: swift, class, iteration, for-in-loop

I am working a project and have come across this error when iterating through a for in loop like this:

```
class CustomClass {
    
    var nameNum : Int { didSet { self.name = "CustomClass \(nameNum)" } }
    var name : String
    
    init() {
        nameNum = 0
        self.name = "CustomClass \(nameNum)"
    }
}

var myArray : [CustomClass] = [CustomClass](repeating: CustomClass(), count: 5)

for _class in myArray.indices {
    myArray[_class].nameNum = _class
}

print("\n")
for _class in myArray.indices {
    print("Item \(_class): \(myArray[_class].name)")
}
```

I get the following output:

> Item 0: CustomClass 4
>
> Item 1: CustomClass 4
>
> Item 2: CustomClass 4
>
> Item 3: CustomClass 4
>
> Item 4: CustomClass 4

This does not make sense to me as I thought I would get the following output instead:

> Item 0: CustomClass 0
>
> Item 1: CustomClass 1
>
> Item 2: CustomClass 2
>
> Item 3: CustomClass 3
>
> Item 4: CustomClass 4

Any help as to why this doesn't work or to how to go about fixing it is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `_class` is a misleading name in the second loop. It's actually an index

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921425/swift-creating-an-array-with-a-default-value-of-distinct-object-instances

Comment: Thanks @MartinR that helps explain it to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your array initialization to

```
var myArray : [CustomClass] = (0..<5).map { _ in CustomClass() }
```

from

```
var myArray : [CustomClass] = [CustomClass](repeating: CustomClass(), count: 5)
```

**Complete Code:**

```
class CustomClass {
    
    var nameNum : Int { didSet { self.name = "CustomClass \(nameNum)" } }
    var name : String
    
    init() {
        nameNum = 0
        self.name = "CustomClass \(nameNum)"
    }
}

var myArray : [CustomClass] = (0..<5).map { _ in CustomClass() }

for _class in myArray.indices {
    myArray[_class].nameNum = _class
}

print("\n")
for _class in myArray.indices {
    print("Item \(_class): \(myArray[_class].name)")
}
```

The reason is that your code, actually creates an instance of `CustomClass` and adds it at all 5 indexes of array where as you are expecting 5 different instance of `CustomClass`. If the same instance is added 5 times, then all of them will have the last set value which in your case is 4.

> Item 0: CustomClass 0
>
> Item 1: CustomClass 1
>
> Item 2: CustomClass 2
>
> Item 3: CustomClass 3
>
> Item 4: CustomClass 4

Comment: Good to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you setting `nameNum` to 0 in the initializer, if you're immediately going to change it? Just combine the operations:

```
class CustomClass {
    var nameNum: Int
    var name: String { return "CustomClass \(nameNum)" }

    init(nameNum: Int) {
        self.nameNum = nameNum
    }
}

var myArray = (0..<5).map(CustomClass.init(nameNum:))

for (index, element) in myArray.enumerated() {
    print("Item #\(index): \(element.name)")
}
```

Also, if `name` always has a value derived from `nameNum`, then it's better to have it be a computed property whose derived from `nameNum`, rather than having the responsibility of setting it fall to a side effect of setting `nameNum`.

Comment: Thank you +1 for the combined operations