# Type error while initializing fixed size array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, hashtable

I'm in the middle of implementing Hash Table using a linked list. 
There are total 3 classes.

```
    class HashNode<Key: Hashable, Value> {
        var key: Key
        var value: Value
        var next: HashNode?

        init(key: Key, value: Value) {
            self.key = key
            self.value = value
        }
    }

    class HashTableBucket<Key: Hashable, Value> {
        typealias Node = HashNode<Key, Value>
        var head: Node?
        var tail: Node?

        func addNode(newNode: Node) {
            //code
        }

        func findNode(key: Key) -> Node?{
             //code
        }
}

struct HashTable<Key: Hashable, Value> {
    private typealias Bucket = HashTableBucket<Key, Value>
    private var buckets: [Bucket]

    private(set) public var count = 0
    private(set) public var capacity = 0

    init(capacity: Int) {
        assert(capacity > 0)
        buckets = Array<Bucket>(repeating: [], count: capacity)
    }

    //other code
}
```

When I initialize the HashTable instance, I want to make a fixed size array which is a type of Bucket(or HashTableBucket) with nil values. I essentially want to make `[[], [], [], [], []]` I'm getting an error on the line `buckets = Array<Bucket>(repeating: [], count: capacity)`. The error says,

```
Playground execution failed: error: HashTable.xcplaygroundpage:163:19: error: cannot invoke initializer for type 'Array<HashTableBucket<Key, Value>>' with an argument list of type '(repeating: [Any], count: Int)'
        buckets = Array<Bucket>(repeating: [], count: capacity)
                  ^

HashTable.xcplaygroundpage:163:19: note: expected an argument list of type '(repeating: Element, count: Int)'
        buckets = Array<Bucket>(repeating: [], count: capacity)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `repeating:` argument is an instance of the array's element type,
e.g.

```
buckets = Array<Bucket>(repeating: Bucket(), count: capacity)
```

to create an array of `Bucket`s. This can be simplified to

```
buckets = Array(repeating: Bucket(), count: capacity)
```

due to automatic type inference.

*However,* (as you noticed in the meantime :) `Bucket` is a class and this will create an array with multiple references to the *same* object instance, which is not what you intend. A possible solution is

```
buckets = (0..<capacity).map { _ in Bucket() }
```

for more, see [Swift: Creating an Array with a Default Value of distinct object instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921425/swift-creating-an-array-with-a-default-value-of-distinct-object-instances).

Comment: Hey Martin I have a quick question. When I initialize `buckets`, do 5 items in the Array all share same instance?

Comment: @user7418039: Indeed, they do, because Bucket is a class (and I should have thought about that). – See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921425/swift-creating-an-array-with-a-default-value-of-distinct-object-instances for possible solutions.