# How to create a matrix of CAShapeLayers?

Tags: swift, cashapelayer

I have this code:

```
var triangles: [[[CAShapeLayer]]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0, count: 2), count: 15), count: 15);
```

But it generates an "Cannot convert value of type..." compilation error.

How can I solve that? I want to access my CAShapeLayers like this:

```
triangles[1][2][1].fillColor = UIColor(red: 40/255, green: 73/255, blue: 80/255, alpha: 1).cgColor;
```

Comment: This post could provide some more insight into your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32921506/8462094

Answer (score 1):

Use optionals.

```
var triangles: [[[CAShapeLayer?]]] = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: Array(repeating: nil, count: 2), count: 15), count: 15)
```

Now there's a nil instead of a 0, which is what I think you were hinting at. But every `triangles[x][y][z]` is now an optional type you'll have to safely unwrap.

So now you have to do something like `triangles[x][y][z] = CAShapeLayer()` before you do anything to that object.

Edit for correction. Thanks @OOPer

---

I thought about it some more, and realized I didn't *really* answer your question.

So you may use for loops to initialize everything (which would be a pain), or you could do something like this every time you access an index:

```
if triangles[x][y][z] == nil
{
    triangles[x][y][z] = CAShapeLayer()
}
let bloop = triangles[x][y][z]!
bloop.fillColor = UIColor(...
```

Then you could pull it out into an outside method so it becomes a 1 liner. Like:

```
func tri(at x: Int, _ y: Int, _ z: Int) -> CAShapeLayer
{
    if triangles[x][y][z] == nil
    {
        triangles[x][y][z] = CAShapeLayer()
    }
    return triangles[x][y][z]!
}
```

Then when using it:

```
tri(at: 1, 2, 1).fillColor = ...
```

Of course, you should pull `triangles` out and make it a property of the class you're in, or you can include it in the parameter list of that 1 liner method.

Comment: Your code does not create 450 objects. It creates just one instance of  `CAShapeLayer` and all elements of `triangles` reference to the same instance.

Comment: Right, I checked the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1641692-init), and doing `Array(repeating: Array(repeating: Array(repeating: CAShapeLayer(), count: 2), count: 15), count: 15)` just makes all indices point to that one instance of CAShapeLayer().

Answer (score 0):

All that nesting makes your code hard to understand, and `Array(repeating:count:)` can't do what you want anyway.

```
func newGrid() -> [[[CAShapeLayer]]] {
    func newStack() -> [CAShapeLayer] {
        return (0 ..< 2).map({ _ in CAShapeLayer() })
    }

    func newRow() -> [[CAShapeLayer]] {
        return (0 ..< 15).map({ _ in newStack() })
    }

    return (0 ..< 15).map({ _ in newRow() })
}

var triangles = newGrid()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use "0" as the repeating value, it will be inferred to be type [[[Int]]]. Just replace "0" with "CAShapeLayer()"