# Swift Array(repeating:, count:) behaviour

Tags: arrays, swift

Why does only one element from the `labels` array appear as a subview of `view`, specifically when using `Array(repeating:, count:)`?

```
let labels = Array(repeating: UILabel(), count: 7)

print(labels.count) //7

let view = UIView()

for label in labels {
    view.addSubview(label)
}

print(view.subviews.count) //1
```

[image: test in the Playground]

Comment: don't post screen shots post your code

Comment: Compare [Creating an Array with a Default Value of distinct object instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921425/swift-creating-an-array-with-a-default-value-of-distinct-object-instances) – all array elements are references to the same label.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because `Array(repeating:count:)` creates an array of 7 variables that are pointing to **the same** label.

Since all 7 elements are pointing to the same instance, the count of the  subviews will be 1.

Answer (score 8):

This is the expected behaviour for `Array.init(repeating:count:)`. Think of its implementation as:

```
// not real code! This is just to illustrate what happens!
init(repeating repeatedValue: Array.Element, count: Int) {
    for _ in 0..<count {
        self.append(repeatedValue)
    }
}
```

Here, no new labels are created. There are just 7 references pointing to the same label.

It's not useful to create 7 labels this way anyway. They would all be in the same position and have the same size and `text`. It would look as if there is only one label. So, just use a for loop.

EDIT

Here is an extension that has the behaviour you want:

```
extension Array {
    init(repeating: (() -> Element), count: Int) {
        self = []
        for _ in 0..<count {
            self.append(repeating())
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like

```
Array(repeating: UILabel.init, count: 7)
```

Since this isn't very useful in creating labels, we can change the closure type to include a `Int` parameter. This way we can create different labels:

```
init(repeating: ((Int) -> Element), count: Int) {
    self = []
    for i in 0..<count {
        self.append(repeating(i))
    }
}

// a horizontal row of square labels!
Array(repeating: { UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: $0 * 100, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)) })
```

This kinda feels like a for loop now...