# Swift: Boolean value remains the same for all instances of class despite assignments in for loop

Tags: swift

I have an array of the following:

```
var shoes = Array(repeating: ShoeInfo(), count: 80)
```

where `ShoeInfo` is defined as follows:

```
class ShoeInfo {
    var expressionOn: Bool?
    var volumeControl: Bool?
    var channel: Int?
}
```

I have a `for` loop:

```
for i in 0..<16 {
    if cond {
        shoeArray[i].expressionOn = true
    } else {
        shoeArray[i].expressionOn = false
    }
}
```

Essentially, the last value assigned in the `for` loop becomes the value for every single class instance in the `shoes` array!

I obviously do not want this. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Swift's convention is to use `UpperCamelCase` for types and `lowerCamelCase` for values. Also, you can just do `for  ... { shoes[i].expressionOn = cond }`

Comment: This is about C++, but it's explaining a similar concept about how Swift structs (objects in C++) and Swift classes (pointers/references to objects in C++) are stored in arrays (`std::vector` in C++)  https://www.cppstories.com/2014/04/vector-of-obj-vs-vector-of-ptr/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32921425/1187415

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### What happened

You only made one instance. You then made an array that contains 80 references to that single instance. See for yourself, try:

```
for shoe in shoes {
    print(ObjectIdentifier(shoe))
}
```

You'll see that all references point to a singular object.

#### What you're probably looking for

is this:

```
let shoes = (0..<80).map { _ in ShoeInfo() }
```

The `map` call will invoke the closure once for each of the 80 integers in the range `0..<80`, which will cause 80 distinct shoe objects to be instantiated.

#### Helpful background

`Array(repeating:_count:_)` takes its parameters by value (notice there's no `inout`). Thus, when you call it, whatever you pass as an argument to the `repeating` parameter, gets copied.

For classes, "copying" entails making a new references to the exact same heap allocated object. It's also usually retained in the process (increasing its reference count by one), but that's not important here. Thus, when you called `Array(repeating: ShoeInfo(), count: 80)`, only a single `ShoeInfo` instance was made, and the code then copied it 80 times, meaning it made 80 copied references to the same one instance.

For structs, "copying" entails fully copying them, member-wise. When you tried `Array(repeating: ShoeInfoAsAStruct(), count: 80)`, you would be creating one `ShoeInfoAsAStruct()`, which would then be copied into each of the 80 slots of the array, causing 80 full copies. You end up with 80 distinct copies at the end, each of which you can edit separately. That's why switching to a `struct` worked.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it by changing the shoeInfo class to a shoeInfo struct.

Not sure of the exact rationale at play however.